# Animated Buttons HTML

Tags: jquery, html, animation

Does anyone know of a good method/tutorial on creating animated buttons using multiple images? I found a tutorial a while back and now can't find one - all resources I can find are for animating between two frames (either by using opacity via jquery or moving the BG image). I'm looking for a way to animate 4-5 frames on rollover and jquery is perfectly fine but I can't find one after an hour on Google. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert, but you could try to chain the animations using jQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function.

Just from looking at the brief documentation, it seems possible to combine the alpha blending technique with each animate() step, by setting the options, queue:true, and setting the complete option to the next animation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Nick! Interesting - I wonder why people seldomly use this method. Seems straightforward enough. I'll look into a tutorial on implementing it, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites2/) is a great one. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Mitch! That's a very hopeful tutorial, the only issue is that it primarily is built for animating between 2 sprites, and either 'fading' or 'sliding' it. I can't for the life of me find a method that integrates several different sprites. What I mean is on MouseOver the button would play frames 1-5 and stop. On MouseOut it would reverse and stop. Pretty simple concept but not very popular